# Why does my SQL throw syntax errors when selecting data from more than one table?

Tags: sql, join

I'm trying to list the email addresses of clients with locations in VIC, but TablePlus tells me I have an error around line 8. Why does this happen? DBMS is MYSQL

```
SELECT
    addresses.id,
    clients.acc_email,
    addresses.state
FROM
    clients,
    addresses 
WHERE
    clients.address_id IN (
        SELECT
            addresses.id,
        FROM
            addresses 
        WHERE
            addresses.state = 'VIC'
    )
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the complete error message

Comment: What DBMS are you using? MySQL? Oracle? SQL Server? ... And hasn't your DBMS given you any more information about the error? What is the exact error message? Is this query really formatted as it was when you got the mesage that the syntax error is around line 8? And whoever taught you to use comma-separated joins (a book, a tutorial, a teacher?): quit and get a better one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a `JOIN` in your `FROM` clause. Try this:

```
SELECT
    addresses.id,
    addresses.state,
    clients.acc_email,
FROM
    addresses JOIN clients ON addresses.id = clients.address_id
WHERE
    addresses.state = 'VIC'
```

Check out [this tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) on joins for more information!

Answer (score 1):

The syntax error result from a comma too many here:

```
    SELECT
        addresses.id,
    FROM
```

which is line 11 in your current formatting.

Apart from that, your query doesn't make much sense. You are selecting all clients with an address in VIC, which is okay, but then you cross join all addresses to these clients, thus combining every VIC client with every address. And you are using an ancient join syntax for this that you shouldn't use anymore. What you seem to want is a mere inner join as has been shown by others already. This would show the client's address information rather than some unrelated one.

```
SELECT
  a.id,
  c.acc_email,
  a.state
FROM addresses a
INNER JOIN clients c ON c.address_id = a.id
WHERE a.state = 'VIC'
ORDER BY c.acc_email;
```

Comment: Hi Thorsten - thanks for your comment although Bawpotter answered the question your answer was the most helpful for me. 

Check for my posts when you browse Stack I'll be posing a lot of SQL questions for the userbase to answer every week.

Answer (score 0):

When you are extracting a result set data from two or multiple tables, you have to ensure that there is some variable (like id ) with which they are joined or connected, some common denominator.
For this, to combine rows from two or more tables in SQL, we have joins.
Your query would look something like below, if the matching part from the tables has to be extracted.

```
select addresses.id,
    clients.acc_email,
    addresses.state   
from
    addresses inner join clients 
on addresses.id = clients.address_id
where
    addresses.state = 'VIC';
```

There are other kinds of joins too, depending on your requirements, you can choose among them.

Read more on Joins in SQL->  https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/